# C# Form using a delay timer with class methods,,,

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to the the site and I am an amateur coder in C# I am attempting Cromwell game of life program in a C# form, I am having an issue with the timer delay, it will delay the program but it will not ran through the code to display the new grid. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(1000 / hScrollBar1.Value);
        timer1.Start();

    }
    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyGrid MyGrid = new MyGrid(panel2, gridTag, uiGenTextBox);
        MyGrid.Update();
        FirstState();
        if (MyGrid.Survived() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No survivers!");
            timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
```

the class: sorry i know there is a lot of code

```
      class MyGrid
      {
       // veriables
       int[,] gen;
       int[,] lastGen;
       int genNumber;
       int gridHeight;
       int gridWidth;
       Panel myPanel = default(Panel);
       private Panel mPanel;
       private TextBox genBox;

    public int GenNumber
    {
        get { return genNumber; }
    }


    public MyGrid(Panel panel2, int[,] gridTag, TextBox uiGenTextBox)
    {
        gen = (int[,])gridTag.Clone();
        genNumber = 0;
        gridWidth = gen.GetLength(1);
        gridHeight = gen.GetLength(0);
        lastGen = new int[gridHeight, gridWidth];
        mPanel = panel2;
        genBox = uiGenTextBox;
    }
    private int GridRule(int x, int y)
    {
        int count = 0;

        // Check for x - 1, y - 1
        if (x > 0 && y > 0)
        {
            if (gen[y - 1, x - 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x, y - 1
        if (y > 0)
        {
            if (gen[y - 1, x] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x + 1, y - 1
        if (x < gridWidth - 1 && y > 0)
        {
            if (gen[y - 1, x + 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x - 1, y
        if (x > 0)
        {
            if (gen[y, x - 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x + 1, y
        if (x < gridWidth - 1)
        {
            if (gen[y, x + 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x - 1, y + 1
        if (x > 0 && y < gridHeight - 1)
        {
            if (gen[y + 1, x - 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x, y + 1
        if (y < gridHeight - 1)
        {
            if (gen[y + 1, x] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        // Check for x + 1, y + 1
        if (x < gridWidth - 1 && y < gridHeight - 1)
        {
            if (gen[y + 1, x + 1] == 1)
                count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
    public void GenSort()
    {
        int[,] nextGen = new int[gridHeight, gridWidth];
        lastGen = (int[,])gen.Clone();
        genNumber++;

        for (int heightLoop = 0; heightLoop < gridHeight; heightLoop++)
        {
            for (int widthLoop = 0; widthLoop < gridWidth; widthLoop++)
            {
                if (GridRule(widthLoop, heightLoop) < 2)
                    nextGen[heightLoop, widthLoop] = 0;
                else if (gen[heightLoop, widthLoop] == 0 &&                  GridRule(widthLoop, heightLoop) == 3)
                    nextGen[heightLoop, widthLoop] = 1;
                else if (gen[heightLoop, widthLoop] == 1 && (GridRule(widthLoop, heightLoop) == 2 || GridRule(widthLoop, heightLoop) == 3))
                    nextGen[heightLoop, widthLoop] = 1;
                else
                    nextGen[heightLoop, widthLoop] = 0;
            }
        }
        gen = (int[,])nextGen.Clone();
    }

    public void Panel_Click2(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            Panel myPanel = ((Panel)sender);
            int locX = myPanel.Location.X / myPanel.Width;
            int locY = myPanel.Location.Y / myPanel.Height;
            if (myPanel.BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                myPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
                gen[locX, locY] = 1;
            }
            else if (myPanel.BackColor == Color.White)
            {
                myPanel.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                myPanel.Tag = 1;
                gen[locX, locY] = 1;
            }
    }

    public void DrawGen()
    {
        int tempValue;
        int tempValue2;
        foreach (Control myPanel in Panel2.Controls)
        {
            int locX = myPanel.Location.X / myPanel.Width;
            int locY = myPanel.Location.Y / myPanel.Height;
            tempValue = gen[locY, locX];
            tempValue2 = lastGen[locY, locX];

            if (tempValue == 0)
            {
                myPanel.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {   
                myPanel.BackColor = Color.White;  
            }
            if (tempValue2 == 1 && tempValue == 0)
            {
               myPanel.BackColor = Color.Crimson;

            }
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        GenSort();
        DrawGen();
        Write();
    }
    public Panel Panel
    {
        get { return (this.myPanel); }
    }
    public Panel Panel2
    {
        get { return (this.mPanel); }
    }
    public TextBox uiGenTextBox
    {
        get { return (this.genBox); }
    }
    public int Survived()
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int heightLoop = 0; heightLoop < gridHeight; heightLoop++)
            for (int widthLoop = 0; widthLoop < gridWidth; widthLoop++)
                if (gen[heightLoop, widthLoop] == 1)
                    count++;

        return count;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't you have infinite loop? You are calling timer.Start() on each interval. Is From freezing? - use Background Worker?

Comment: I need it in a loop to go run the process and the rules and the class, but i need it to update the grid each time it goes through the loop, if i use a while loop with thread,sleep it works the way i need it to but it blocks the UI, so im a little stuck.

Comment: also im not sure what background worker is ??

Comment: Did yout try using Background worker and putting loop inside DoWork event. http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker Executes an operation on a separate thread. Won't block UI

Comment: How would I do that ? I know the basics of the timer function but more than that im stumped. i have used thread,sleep() but that locks the UI

Comment: You may just need to add a call to `Refresh()` after you update the grid.

Comment: Also, do you mean Conway's game of life, or is this some variant I've not heard of?

Comment: You don't need to keep calling `timer1.Start()` in `timer1_Tick`. Also, make sure that whatever you're doing in that loop does not take longer than the timer interval. Finally, are you sure that you want to create and initialize a new grid every timer tick?

Comment: even with Refresh() it still only goes to the first generation of the grid after that it freezes

Comment: It's suspicious that you call something called `FirstState()` every timer tick.. We can't see the code for `MyGrid`, so it's not clear how it's supposed to be used. Does the timer code execute every tick? (set a breakpoint)

Comment: sorry yes i mean conway's game of life,  Yes i do need to initialize/create a new grid each time because that is what takes in the first instance of the grid to start with.

Comment: I agree with Chris, `timer1.Start()` and don't create new grid.  Considering you are new, I would recommend you stick with timers and **don't** use threads, `BackgroundWorker` or otherwise.   It will just confuse the issue and lead to potentially new problems

Comment: firstState() just draws the panels,

Comment: the funny thing is the thread work but the timer doesn't lol

Comment: but the thread blocks UI

Comment: but i have to call gridTag(which is an array) in MyGrid MyGrid so that it will be taken into the class